# Otimizar firebase cloud storage

Tags: firebase

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação usando o *Firebase Realtime Database* e o *Firebase Cloud Storage*. De acordo com a [documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files?hl=pt-br#download_data_via_url), para acessar uma imagem eu preciso invocar o método *getDownloadURL* na referência do path em que ela foi salva.

Imagine que eu tenha uma lista desenhada em um loop, e para cada registro eu tenha de 2 a 3 imagens, é muito custoso para a aplicação invocar esse método para cada imagem que eu precisar exibir na tela. Alguma maneira de melhorar essa lógica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu sugiro que você faça o `getDownloadURL()` quando fizer o upload da imagem para o Storage. Daí você pega esse url e guarda no seu banco de dados.

Quando você for ler os dados, irá ler também o downloadURL. Não precisa mais invocar o método.

Comment: A primeira coisa que pensei foi isso, mas é seguro fazer isso sabendo que existe um token na queryString da url que pode expirar algum dia?

Comment: O token só expira se for revogado diretamente na consola do Firebase.